# Android microphone input sensitivity

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

I got the droid bionic recently.  Nice phone, except for all the garbage Moto/Verizon force on you.

In the past I've tried to record live audio with my other phones, and its always a distorted mess.  The input is too high and clips the mic.

The bionic has a "concert" mode with the video recorder.  Its actually fantastic (all things considered).
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxKnQT7r18M
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNz6ubPAFGk

If I had to put money on it, I'd guess this is a moto/bionic specific feature.  If not, I'd love to be able to do this with my own code.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Example of "distorted mess" from my G2: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRthUvKe1bE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found nothing for this.  Must be a custom bionic thing.